# Is there a way to select multiple layers and move them as one in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, gnu

I have an image I'm working on and it has a lot of layers in an area. I want to move all of these layers to another side of the image without merging them all or moving them individually.

I know how to do this normally, but that way only moves the layer you're working on, not all layers in the selection.

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain layers together and then move them. The chaining is done in the layers dialog and the move by the move tool.